# What is the output of following code

Tags: java

It should print only Number: -1
but it is printing Number: -1 0 1 2
Why it is printing this series?
I expect execution will go only once to `System.out.println`.

```
class MemoryJava {  
     public static void main(String[] args){
        decreaseNumberbyOne(2);
    }   
    public static void decreaseNumberbyOne(int num){    
        if(num >= 0){           
            decreaseNumberbyOne(num -1);
        }   
        System.out.println("Number:"+num);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of recursion?

Comment: there is mistake in your code, the `System.out.println("Number:"+num);` execute after if condition, if you want `System.out.println("Number:"+num);` to execute when num <0 keep it in else block

Comment: Because this is a recursive method. https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-is-recursion-in-java-programming/ follow this tutorial and you'll learn how recursion works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sequence of events:

- call (2)
- call (1)
- call (0)
- call (-1)
- do not call (-2) because <0
- print -1
- return
- print 0
- return
- print 1
- return
- print 2
- return

It is called recursion.

I would show code with an `else` to help you achieve the desired output, but for that look at the other answer by deadpool.

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: I got the idea about this series printing. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this will work, just mistake in your code, add `System.out.println("Number:"+num);` in else block

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    decreaseNumberbyOne(2);
}   
public static void decreaseNumberbyOne(int num){    
    if(num >= 0){           
        decreaseNumberbyOne(num -1);
    } else{  
    System.out.println("Number:"+num);
     }
}
```